Hardy-type inequality and an identity about the square of laplacian
It can be verified by using integrating by parts, that
\begin{aligned}
\langle \nabla (fg^{-1})\cdot \nabla (fg^{-1}),g^2\rangle&=-\langle fg^{-1}, \Delta (fg^{-1})g^2\rangle-\langle fg^{-1}, 2g \nabla g\cdot \nabla (fg^{-1})\rangle\\
&=-\langle \Delta(fg),fg^{-1}\rangle+2\langle \nabla (f\nabla g), fg^{-1}\rangle\\
&=\langle -\Delta f,f\rangle+\langle f^2,g^{-1}\Delta g\rangle\\
&=\| \nabla f\|_2^2+\int f^2 \cfrac{\Delta g}{g}
\end{aligned}
Note that, if we take $g=(1+|x|^2)^{(n-2)/2}$ which satifies that
$$
\Delta g= C g^{(n+2)(n-2)}
$$
then we have proved the following Hardy-type inequality
$$
\|\nabla f\|_2^2 \geq -C \int \cfrac{f^2}{(1+|x|^2)^2}.
$$
My question is: do we have that
$$
\langle \Delta(fg^{-1})\Delta(fg^{-1}),g^2\rangle =\langle \Delta f,\Delta f\rangle -\langle f^2,\cfrac{\Delta^2 g}{g}\rangle
$$
and hence we can use this to prove a similar forth-order Hardy-type inequality.

The claim is not correct. We still have  $\Delta (fg^{-1}), \nabla(fg^{-1})$ and $\Delta g$ on the right hand side. However, fortunately, we can show that  $\langle \Delta^2 f,f\rangle -\langle f^2, g^{-1}\Delta^2 g\rangle \geq 0$
